# .Net MVC file upload control in modal popup and save using $.post

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, file-upload

I an trying to upload file using modal popup. I couldn't get uploaded file in controller.
I placed file upload control in model popup and used $.post to save that file.
Please suggest me your thoughts, It's possible or not?
Thanks!

Comment: Guys, If you have any idea Please share with me!

Answer (score 0):

No, out of the box `$.post` cannot be used to upload files. You could use some of the available file upload plugins such as [`jQuery.form`](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/) or [`Blueimp file upload`](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload).